# Debugging C/C++ NDK library in AndroidStudio

Tags: c++, debugging, android-studio, android-ndk, toolchain

I am having problem with debugging C++ code in Android Studio. First a bit about setup:

1. C++ source code is stored in /tmp/pjsip directory, compiled with standalone toolchain for a particular Android target.
2. Resulting library is passed through SWIG which produces libpjsua2.so and has JNIs already available
3. Android Project is setup in another directory and library from step #2 is copied into `app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a` directory and Java JNI code is stored in `app/src/main/java/org/pjsip/pjsua2` directory.

[Directory structure is as follows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y8VV.png)

If I now debug Android app all my code tracing ends in a set of files stored under `app/src/main/java/org/pjsip/pjsua2` directory where Java JNIs for code written in C/C++ are. I can't debug and go any further towards code in C/C++. That's my problem. I tried modifying Android.mk and build.gradle files by following some hints on the internet but no luck so far.

Here is the content of Android.mk file:

```
include ../../../../../build.mak
LOCAL_PATH  := $(PJDIR)/pjsip-apps/src/swig/java/android
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libpjsua2
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := $(APP_CXXFLAGS) -frtti -fexceptions
LOCAL_LDFLAGS   := $(APP_LDXXFLAGS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := $(APP_LDXXLIBS)
#LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := $(APP_LDXXLIBS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../output/pjsua2_wrap.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And here is the content of build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.fortinet.fvuc.app"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 21
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 21
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'));
        }
    }

    android.ndk {
       moduleName = "libpjsua2"
    }

}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.0.+'
    compile 'com.intellij:annotations:+@jar'
}
```

Build.gradle(Main Project) looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

How do I tell Android Studio where my source code is so that I can debug the library written in C/C++?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you happen to find a solution for this?

Comment: No, not yet. I found a less elegant work-around for this problem. It's not generally applicable so no point to elaborate more on it. I'll have to look into it again some time soon.